# Connecting headphones to two different CSR8510 A10 dongles without repairing

Tags: bluetooth, dongle

I own a Sony WH-1000XM2 and would like to connect it to my home PC and work PC over bluetooth. I ordered and installed two USB bluetooth dongles ORICO USB Bluetooth Adapter 4.0 (BTA-403) (http://www.orico.cc/goods.php?id=6004).

I can pair up and connect my headphones to my computer without any issues at home. Subsequent connections also succeed. However, I can't connect them to my work PC without re-pairing. After repairing at work I can then no longer connect them to my home PC without re-pairing. My guess is that the headphones think both dongles are the same dongle which causes connectivity issues.

I'm using generic MS Windows 10 Bluetooth drivers at home and generic MS Windows 7 Bluetooth drivers at work. The manufacturer provided drivers 'CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack' don't seem to work at all (can't pair or connect my device using those drivers).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay managed to solve this and its what I expected. Both dongles share the same MAC address.

MAC Address : (00:1A:7D:DA:71:13)
Chip maker : Cambridge Silicon Radio

You can use these tools:
https://macaddresschanger.com/
http://blog.petrilopia.net/linux/change-your-bluetooth-device-mac-address/

To change your dongle's MAC address and make them unique. Then after repairing both devices again I can connect to both without repairing and everything works as expected.